# SignalR and OwinContext = System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin, objectdisposedexception

I have an Asp.Net application using SignalR.
When I try to call the OwinContext (in the signalR hub), I got a System.ObjectDisposedException.

I use my OwinContext like this :

`Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`

Here is my StartUp class:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            CookieName = "AspNetIdentityAuth",
            CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cookieDomain"]
        });
```

All works fine on my W7 dev machine with IISExpress. The problem appear only on a W2012R2 server with IIS8.5.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: You might be hitting this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2972